# Django CMS modify plugin for installed app via pip

Tags: python, django, plugins, django-cms

I would like to know how to achieve the following for apps installed via pip:

1. Show only specific fields when editing the plugins in the cms
2. Override the verbose name of some of the models showed when editing the plugins
3. Restrict the length of the fields
4. Add new fields to the models

For reference, my app installed via pip is aldryn-newsblog.

Would be great if any of this would be possible.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well an app installed through `pip` is already written by someone. So what should happen in case the length of certain fiels is longer? Rejecting to install? Try to rename the fields? What if name clashes occur?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OK, then, let's say I just want to restrict what the user can input with a form or how the field is shown to the user. Is this still not possible? I know that you can assign a form for the plugins to change it's default behaviour, but how to do for external plugins?